# how to identify extra-tall symbols?

Tags: symbols, line-spacing, amssymb

I am trying to typeset some long lines of formula as densely as possible. (This is for art, not math.) Some few of the 400+ symbols from amssymb / amsmath have risers or descenders and therefore increase the line spacing -- I'd like to remove them. They are not apparent to me at a glance, though. How can I identify which are the extra-tall symbols?

I am aware there are other means of adjusting line spacing, but if only a handful of symbols are causing this problem, I can easily work around them.

Comment: So what form of solution do you seek?  A list of tall symbols?  Code that rejects symbols beyond a certain height/depth?  A font table of symbols provided by amsmath?  More generally, what does the code you are dealing with currently look like?

Comment: If you look at the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf),  you can find tables summarizing all the variable sized delimiters and operators.

Comment: \resizebox and \scalebox (graphics or graphicx pakcages) can be used to change the aspect ratio for everything inside.

Comment: I don’t think that any artistic creation can adequately represent modern (as opposed to ancient) mathematics without featuring the integral sign… :-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I wondered if I could reveal the boxes containing each symbol.